# Radio Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, addition

I have `radiobutton`s like below:

```
Apple
<input type="radio" id="one" name="apple" data-price="10" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="two" name="apple" data-price="20" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="appleqty" name="appleqty" value="" />

Mango
<input type="radio" id="three" name="Mango" data-price="30" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="one" name="Mango" data-price="40" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Mangoqty" name="Mangoqty" value="" />

Pine Apple
<input type="radio" id="four" name="Pineapple" data-price="50" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="five" name="Pineapple" data-price="60" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />

Grape
<input type="radio" id="six" name="Grape" data-price="70" value="light"/> Light
<input type="radio" id="seven" name="Grape" data-price="80" value="dark" /> Dark
<input type="text" id="Pineappleqty" name="Pineappleqty" value="" />
​
```

The `radiobutton`s are separated in a `Group` as `(Apple,Mango,Pineapple,Grape)`.
I need to add the `Price` with the `Quantity` he needs.

### Example:

If a user clicked `Dark Apple` in the `radiobutton` with `1 Qty` the `Price` should be `20` and if the user changed the clicked `Radio` to the `Light Apple` `radiobutton` then the price should be `10 - 20(Previous Price If Checked) = 10` .
Is this possible using JavaScript?

My code that I have tried:

```
function upprice(ref)
{
    var elname = ref.getAttribute("name");
    var qtyname = elname+"qty";
    var price = ref.getAttribute("proprice");
    var qty = parseInt(document.getElementById(qtyname).value)
    var newprice = parseInt(price*qty);
    var olprice = parseInt(document.getElementById("orderpagepriceinstant").innerHTML);
    var totalprice = parseInt(olprice+newprice);
    document.getElementById("orderpagepriceinstant").innerHTML = parseInt(totalprice)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ascii-lime i am very new to javascript so i am trying to learn about it sir

Comment: Trial and error, and lots of research is how I have learned js.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Daedalus i am very new to javascript so i am trying to learn about it sir

Comment: You can't learn without trying something.

Comment: @vaahost which books or articles have you read about JS?

Comment: @Kolyunya i am learning from w3schools.com

Comment: Kindly Check My Above Question I Have Added My Javascript Code That I Have Tried

Comment: Then this is an intervention; please read [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com).  Also, why did you capitalize every first letter of every word?

Comment: Note that `id` is supposed to be unique, but you've used `id="one"` twice (one of the apple radios and one of the mango radios).

Comment: @nnnnnn its just a typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick jQuery example: http://jsfiddle.net/FTscC/

(laptop dying, I'll elaborate when I can tomorrow!)

Comment: its working but can i get it in pure javascript.. not in jquery

Comment: You can invoke javascript method using `onclick()` event for radio button.   And, read or modify attribute of elements using `getAttribute()` or `setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your inputs should be something like:

```
<input type="radio" name="apple" value="10">Light
<input type="radio" name="apple" value="20">Dark
<input type="text" name="appleqty" value="">
```

You can put a click listener on the radio buttons and a change listener on the quantity to update the price:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="updatePrice(this)" ...>
<input type="text" onclick="updatePrice(this)" ...>
```

and the update function is:

```
function updatePrice(el) {
  var priceEach, quantity, itemValue;

  if (el.type == 'radio') {
    priceEach = getRBValue(el);
    quantity = el.form[el.name + 'qty'].value;

  } else if (el.type == 'text') {
    quantity = el.value;
    priceEach = getRBValue(el.form[el.name.replace(/qty$/,'')]);
  }

  /* 
     code here to validate the value of quantity
  */

  itemValue = quantity * priceEach;


  /* 
     do something with itemValue
  */

  alert(itemValue);
}

// Get the value of a radio button set
function getRBValue(el) {
  var buttons;

  // See if have been passed a button or button set (NodeList)
  if (el.type == 'radio') {
    buttons = el.form[el.name];
  } else if (typeof el.length == 'number') {
    buttons = el;
  }

  if (buttons) {
    for (var i=0, iLen=buttons.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (buttons[i].checked) {
        return buttons[i].value;
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

The markup, you can also add a click listener to the form to do updates rather than on each radio button. You should also have a reset button so the user can clear the form.

```
<form ... >
    <input type="radio" name="apple" value="10" onclick="updatePrice(this)">Light
    <input type="radio" name="apple" value="20" onclick="updatePrice(this)">Dark
    <input type="text" name="appleqty" value="" onchange="updatePrice(this)">
    <br>
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry Sir Its Not Working For Me

Comment: It's just an example of an approach, it "works" for me. Can you explain "not working"? Error messages, incorrect value, etc. Note that I didn't use the *data-price* attribute because radio buttons already have a value attribute that can be used for that purpose. So you might need to change `el.value` to `el.getAttribute('data-price')` and so on.

Comment: i get this error el.form is null  priceEach = getRBValue(el.form[el.name.replace(/qty$/,'')]);
el.form is null  buttons = el.form[el.name];

Comment: Put the form controls in a form.